# Add iPod Equalizer effect using AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

Im have a problem with Equalizer, i want add some Equalizer filter to my music app using AVAudioPlayer.

Some effect like : Acoustic,Bass Booster Classical...

Please help me, any suggestions or answers are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi kim, are you able to add equalizer now? If you are could you please provide me the solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not add equalizer for AVAudioPlayer. For equalizer you need use AUGraph and audio units.

Comment: Dzmitry, could you please provide me the example for this. I need to add EQ effects to my recorded audio for an iOS application.